# Specify alternate tsconfig.json for VS Code / ts-node / ts-node-dev

Tags: visual-studio-code, tsconfig, ts-node, ts-node-dev

I'm migrating my project from JavaScript to Typescript.

I want to have the default `tsconfig.json` to show stricter warnings in VS Code, but have an alternate `tsconfig.json` with more lenient `tsc` compiler options to allow a successful build.

The migration plan is to gradually `strict`-ify the options in the alternate, just-compile-it-dammit `tsconfig-dev.json` file over time.

I can pass `--project alt-tsconfig.json` to `tsc` to specify an alternative `tsconfig.json`.

How can I specify which `tsconfig.json` to use with `ts-node` and `ts-node-dev`?

Answer (score 5):

For both `ts-node` and `ts-node-dev`, you can pass:

```
-P tsconfig-dev.json
```

to specify an alternative path for `tsconfig.json`.

Alternatively, you can set the variable:

```
TS_NODE_PROJECT=tsconfig-dev.json
```

The latter also works for VS Code, which you may want do do via:

```
"env": { "TS_NODE_PROJECT": "tsconfig-dev.json" }.
```